# what is sum of largest divisor not divisible by a given prime

Tags: math, logic

Gine 2 numbers N and M, what will be sum of largets divisors of all numbers between [1 to n] that are not divisible by M. for example:- N=10, M=3, then the sum will be 41 as largets divisors from 1 to 10 is [1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 7, 8, 1, 10], that is not divisible by 3 and sum of which is 41.

Answer (score 0):

So the sum of numbers 1 to N is N(N+1)/2. If M > N, this is the answer; otherwise, we have overcounted. By how much did we overcount? We overcounted every multiple of M less than or equal to N. Let's try to see by how much we overcounted. We overcounted the terms divisible by M; their sum is M + 2M + … + floor(N/M)*M. As a first pass, we can subtract this sum, and add back the sum divided by M:

```
  M + 2M + … + floor(N/M)*M
= M(1 + 2 + … + floor(N/M))
= M*floor(N/M)*(floor(N/M) + 1)/2
```

The resulting expression:

```
N(N+1)/2 + (1 - M)*floor(N/M)*(floor(N/M) + 1)/2
```

This gets us a lot closer to where we need to be. We have replaced all terms of the form kM with just k. However, we have still overcounted if M^2 < N; the terms of the form kM^2 are still divisible by M. So, we can repeat the process, getting an expression like:

```
  N(N+1)/2
+ (1 - M)*floor(N/M)*(floor(N/M) + 1)/2
+ (1 - M)*floor(N/M^2)*(floor(N/M^2) + 1)/2
+ …
+ (1 - M)*floor(N/M^k)*(floor(N/M^k) + 1)/2
```

You can terminate the process once floor(N/M^k) = 0, that is, once M^k > N. Your example:

```
  10(10+1)/2
+ (1 - 3)*floor(10/3)*(floor(10/3) + 1)/2
+ (1 - 3)*floor(10/9)*(floor(10/9) + 1)/2
= 10*11/2
+ -2*3*4/2
+ -2*1*2/2
= 55
- 12
- 2
= 41
```

You can calculate this in a loop pretty efficiently; the termination condition would be the current power of M is greater than N.

Comment: Does this approach work if `M` is not prime?